# how to expose limited number of operation contracts to a service consumer?

Tags: wcf

I have a Service Contract with 5 operations contracts and hosted in IIS.

Let suppose I have 2 Service Consumer A & B.

I need to give access to all 5 operations contracts to Service Consumer A, but
for Service Consumer B, I need to give access to only 2 out of 5 operations contracts.

What settings we need to do to expose only 2 operations contracts to  Consumer B?

Thanks

Comment: One way is to have two different implementations.  IServiceB could define the two methods used by consumer B, and IServiceA could inherit from IServiceB and add three more methods, and then Service A would implement IServiceA and Service B would implement IServiceB.  That could get cumbersome though if you have a lot of consumers with varying requirements.

Comment: then how to create 2 different endpoint, one with access to 5 and other with 2 methods access?

Comment: Assuming you manage to do what you want technically, what would you do if customer B simply calls the service for customer A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Tim's Comment I would create the two contracts and have two endpoints but you would only need one implementation like follows

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService_AdminLvl : IService_USERLvl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string setData(int value);
        [OperationContract]
        string setData2(int value);
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface  IService_USERLvl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData2(int value);
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData3(int value);
    }




    public class Service1 : IService_AdminLvl
    {
        //IMPL ALL FUCNTIONS 
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }  
        public string GetData2(int value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string GetData3(int value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public string setData(int value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string setData2(int value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

and a config something like this...

```
 <service name="domainName.Service_2">
  <endpoint address="admin" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="domainName.IService_AdminLvl">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="user" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="domainName.IService_UserLvl">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</service>
```

Comment: got it, Service Contract Inheritance, looks like Interface Segregation Principal from SOLID.  thanks!